# How to Match Memory to FSB (pre IMC)

Tags: memory, performance, cpu, motherboard, bandwidth

### I have the following hardware:

- P35-DS3L supporting FSB 333/266/200 Mhz, quad-pumped. Four dual-channel slots.
- E2180 currently @ 2.00Ghz (200.00x10)

I plan to raise the FSB to 266.66.

### This is my visualization of the block diagram:

```
                                                                                                               ------------------------
                                                                                                           --> |[64-bit]2x SDRAM DIMMs|
-----                       -----------------------------------------------------                        /     ------------------------
|CPU|  <-- FSB [64-bit]-->  |Northbridge (Intel P35): Memory Controller[128-bit]|  <-- Memory I/O Bus ---
-----                       -----------------------------------------------------                        \     ------------------------
                                                                                                           --> |[64-bit]2x SDRAM DIMMs|
                                                                                                               ------------------------
```

### Matching Memory Using Bandwidth

I was having trouble accounting for the mismatch between the FSB and Memory I/O Bus frequencies, until I found [this elegant answer](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=4301183#p4301183) suggesting to match bandwidth instead of frequency.

```
bandwidth = [bus clock] * [data rate] * [data width] / 8
```

The bandwidth on the (quad-pumped) FSB side:

```
FSB@200.00MHz   =   200.00 * 4 (for quad-pumped) * 64 / 8 = 6400 MB/s
FSB@266.66MHz   =   266.66 * 4 (for quad-pumped) * 64 / 8 = 8533 MB/s
```

Now to match this bandwidth on the memory side for a *single* DIMM:

```
FSB@200.00MHz   =   DDR2-800    : 400.00 * 2 * 64 / 8 = 6400 MB/s
FSB@266.66MHz   =   DDR2-1066   : 533.33 * 2 * 64 / 8 = 8533 MB/s
```

Now to match this bandwidth on the memory side for dual-channel:

```
FSB@200.00MHz   =   DDR2-400    : 200.00 * 2 * 64 / 8 * 2 (for dual channel) = 6400 MB/s
FSB@266.66MHz   =   DDR2-533    : 266.66 * 2 * 64 / 8 * 2 (for dual channel) = 8533 MB/s
```

Now however there is no guarantee that the memory requests will be balanced equally between both channels. Each request to the memory controller in a dual-channel layout may have a benefit ranging from [1..2]. For example, given an FSB@200.00MHz and two DIMMs of DDR2-400 in separate channels, if the CPU requests 64 bits of data solely from channel 1 (none from channel 2), then that particular request will need by completed over two transfers.

Therefore, my conclusion is to purchase two DIMMs of DDR2-1066 SDRAM in anticipation of overclocking the FSB to 266.66MHz. **Is this correct?**

Of course, given 50/50 odds (ie a linear efficacy of the dual channels), faster RAM provides diminishing returns, especially compared to $$. And perhaps the CPU is *always* able to batch memory requests to *always* utilize most efficiently the dual channels, in which case I should instead purchase two DIMMs of DDR2-533 in anticipation of overclocking the FSB to 266.66MHz? **Or is this correct?**

### Matching Memory Using Frequency

How would I perform the same calculation by matching frequencies instead of bandwidth? The [wikipedia article on memory dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_divider) provides an example I don't understand.

The memory divider denotes the ratio between the FSB frequency and the Memory I/O Bus frequency. If, as per the article, the FSB operates at 200MHz with a memory divider of 1:1, then the Memory I/O Bus also operates at 200MHz. The article then claims this is compatible with DDR2-800 SDRAM. Why? DDR2-800 SDRAM operates at 400MHz, not 200MHz.

My working assumption is that the memory divider only denotes the ratio of effective (not actual) frequencies. For example, quad-pumped FSB of 200MHz has an effective data transfer rate of 800Mhz. Dual-data rate operating at 400MHz has an effective data transfer rate of also 800Mhz. This implies the memory I/O Bus actually runs at 400MHz, a fact glossed over in the memory divider ratio. **Is this correct?**

From what I gather, the RAM prefetch buffer is also completely immaterial to this discussion. The prefetch buffer is completely internal to the DIMMs: it allows the internal memory clock to run at half the Memory I/O Bus clock without a drop in bandwidth.

Comment: I've highlighted the three questions I'd like answered **bold**.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to assume that if you raise the base clock to 266 MHz it will result in the front side bus (x4, being quad pumped) speed of 1066 MHz.  Using DDR3 memory with a speed of 1066 MHz would result in a 1:2 ratio because the frequency would be 533MHz (x2, for Double Data Rate memory modules.)  That is assuming that your motherboard supports 1066 MHz DDR3 memory modules.  Check the motherboard manufacturers website for the memory support list for that specific motherboard to see if the modules you have in mind have been validated.